# PHP self server not working

Tags: php, html

I am using easyPHP. I don't really understand (despite doing plenty of research) why I continue to get a ERROR 404 when I hit the "Make the change button". Below is an example of what I am trying to do.  The goal is to have a submit button that refers to a php function in the current document.  I have several working (but complicated) examples from my teacher but I cannot seam to recreate the concept of having a document refer to itself for a function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!   EDIT:The file is saved as a PHP file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]" method = "POST">
<input type = "submit" name = "modify" value = "Make the change" />
</form>
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['modify'])) // if the modify button is clicked.
{
echo "IT WORKED";
}
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>

Comment: check my answer I tried it and it worked.

Comment: please accept the answers those solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] is a **PHP global variable** and you need to wrap it with **PHP code block** and add single quotes on 'PHP_SELF'.

```
<form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 1):

it will be

```
<form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method = "POST">
```

Comment: The file is already saved with a .php extension. Also I tried pasting in your answer and it didn't work. Any other ideas....

Comment: This will not work since you are not putting single quotes on PHP_SELF.

Comment: @user3600424 try <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> with the single quotes around PHP_SELF

Comment: <form action = "$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]" method = "POST">  This line is directly copied and pasted from a .php file that does work.  THis is why I'm so confused.

Comment: @user3600424 I tried your code check my answer it will work for you.

Comment: Thankyou John Robertson!! Im not sure why it works the other way in the other files my teacher gave me but if I can get this to work for my project then thats good enough for me!!

Comment: @user3600424 accept my answer to make known to others that it's already solved.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it necessary for you to use `action = "$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]"` But you can omit the it to make it work. by default it the action is same page itself. So you code would look like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method = "POST">
<input type = "submit" name = "modify" value = "Make the change" />
</form>
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['modify'])) // if the modify button is clicked.
    {
        echo "IT WORKED";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```